# Sum of all positive and negative numbers in string

Tags: python, string

I have a string of numbers that have negative and positive numbers like so:

```
number = "17,1,29,17,1,-6,-16,-16,29,3,29,18,3,19,-17,28"
```

Like this code works, but it ignores negative number as negatives and adds them like positives. The sum suppose to be 139 and not 114.

```
def sumNumbers(number):
    return sum(int(x) for x in number if x.isdigit())
```

And I dont know how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split by `','`:

```
numbers = "17,1,29,17,1,-6,-16,-16,29,3,29,18,3,19,-17,28"
result = sum(map(int, numbers.split(',')))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
139
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split() the string:

```
number = "17,1,29,17,1,-6,-16,-16,29,3,29,18,3,19,-17,28"

sum = 0
for nr in number.split(','):
    sum+=int(nr)

print(sum)
# 139
```